# When would the branch "native-contract-debugging" be merged to the master?

Tags: smart-contract, debug

I've gotten a message that there would be a better method to debug a custom contract from Telegram. This would be implemented in the branch "native-contract-debugging" which would be merged to the master soon.
Does anyone know how it is going? And are there some tutorials to indicate how to use that feature?

Comment: Questions relating to "when would this feature be implemented" is really something that should not be asked on eosio.stackexchange.  The questions asked here should be of _wiki_ quality, that can be of use to future readers of the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can find out yourself in Github, apparently it hasn't been merged to master nor slim.

https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/compare/master...native-contract-debugging?expand=1

Comment: thanks for your help. I've changed  the tittle . Actually, I want to know when it would be merged to the master and how to use such new feature.